# c# picturebox to control not working

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox, windows-forms-designer, maze

I am following a tutorial on how to make a recursive maze in c#.
this is the tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4a950c/solving-mazes-using-recursion/

i was following these steps,but I can't get any further because when I run this code, the picture boxes won't show up as in the tutorial.

this is the part where they should be made:

```
private void createNewMaze()
    {
        mazeTiles = new PictureBox[XTILES, YTILES];
        //Loop for getting all tiles
        for (int i = 0; i < XTILES; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < YTILES; j++)
            {
                //initialize a new PictureBox array at cordinate XTILES, YTILES
                mazeTiles[i, j] = new PictureBox();
                //calculate size and location
                int xPosition = (i * TILESIZE) ; //13 is padding from left
                int yPosition = (j * TILESIZE) ; //45 is padding from top
                mazeTiles[i, j].SetBounds(xPosition, yPosition, TILESIZE, TILESIZE);
                //make top left and right bottom corner light blue. Used for start and finish
                if ((i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == XTILES - 1 && j == YTILES - 1))
                    mazeTiles[i, j].BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                else
                {
                    //make all other tiles white
                    mazeTiles[i, j].BackColor = Color.White;
                    //make it clickable
                    EventHandler clickEvent = new EventHandler(PictureBox_Click);
                    mazeTiles[i, j].Click += clickEvent; // += used in case other events are used

                }
                //Add to controls to form (display picture box)
               this.Controls.Add(mazeTiles[i, j]);

            } 
        }
    }
```

this is what i get:
[Maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLsjF.png)

i can't find the solution, maybe someone can, thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you're showing looks fine (and it works for me). Are you sure this method is getting called? Do you have a `CreateNewMaze();` line in your `Form()` constructor?

Comment: that's the problem, while debugging, this method is not being called

Comment: Show your form constructor, then...

Comment: ahh sorry, I did not call the method, thanks for the help! :P

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            createNewMaze();
        }